# check similarity/plagiarism between articles in mysql via python

Tags: python, mysql, plagiarism-detection

i have a mysql database where i add news articles, and before adding to it it try to compere that article with 100 last articles if it has any similarity.

so if is 95% similar i can tag it as  **same** as article 122 or if it is 70-95% similar i can tag it as **similar** to article 133,

Which is best way to do this:

> 1. is there a way or a function that mysql can do it
> 2. do i need to use python to compare that article in a while loop with other 100 articles

as i read in forums python is the best way, but i tried some library to compare string1(article1) with string2(article2)  and even if its totally different article it tell me it is 70% same

> i think it is because of some same words like : ***and , he ,she, will,
> news,text,or,and, the, i***

Answer (score -1):

> as i read in forums python is the best way, but i tried some library
> to compare string1(article1) with string2(article2) and even if its
> totally different article it tell me it is 70% same
>
> i think it is because of some same words like : and , he ,she, will,
> news,text,or,and, the, i

I will suggest to remove stopwords, might help.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD;
```

default mysql STOPWORDS. For Information look at the [MYSQL Full-Text Stopwords Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) &
[Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Linux you can call from python the diff command and play with the parameters, a teacher a few years ago did this to detect copy in a programing exam, it worked even after reformatting the code